# Git/github command line app that uses oauth tokens to authenticate?

Tags: git, authentication, command-line, oauth, github

I wish to use a simple command line client (such as the official git client) to clone branches from github as part of a deploy tool.

For security, I do not wish to use basic (username/password) authentication. As I am already using github's oauth-token based Auth headers in my app, I was wondering if there is a **command-line app that can use oauth tokens to authenticate to github**.

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, you don't need any authentication if you clone open Github projects. Or do you specifically need access to ones requiring the authenticated access?

Comment: @fork0 I specifically need to access private projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update Sep 2012**

[Github now accepts the use of auth tokens using any git client](https://github.com/blog/1270-easier-builds-and-deployments-using-git-over-https-and-oauth).

You can [get a oauth token for github using these instructions](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#create-a-new-authorization), here's a practical demo using Node.js and superagent.

```
var GITHUB_API_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.github.com/'

superagent
  .post(GITHUB_API_ENDPOINT+'authorizations')
  .auth('username', 'notactuallymypassword')
  .send({ scopes: 'repo', note: 'Social Ops Deployer' })
  .end(function(res){
    if (res.ok) {
     console.log('yay got ' + JSON.stringify(res.body));
    } else {
     console.log('Oh no! error ' + res.text);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard of any.

And you probably already discovered the [official documentation on this topic](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/) describing how such client could be developed.

But I think it might create additional development overhead and probably introducing bugs, so maybe it's worth to try different approaches to solving this issue? For example:

- using ssh protocol to retrieve data from github;
- introducing new user in the team with 'pull-only' permissions and using his credentials.

Comment: that's exactly what I ended up doing - using [machine users](https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys) (see 'Machine Users' heading) with read-only access to a selected group of projects.